# Using weakref for implementing logic

Tags: python, weak-references

I have a `Node` class representing nodes and I want to have a dictionary mapping nodes to sets of nodes.

```
{Node: set(Node)}
```

Now, such a dictionary would need to be updated whenever a node is 'deleted'. Not only would the node need to be removed from the 'keys' of the dictionary, it would also need to be removed from any 'value set' that it is a part of.

`weakref` provides a way to implement this logic without any extra effort at all; the set becomes a `WeakSet` and the `dict` becomes a `WeakKeyDictionary` and the 'updates' now happen automatically.

But, most of the discussions on `weakref` suggest that it should be used to prevent reference cycles and to implement caches etc. Is it a good idea to use weak references to implement the core logic like above? Specifically, are there any dangers to relying on the garbage collector to do things which would normally be manually implemented.

Comment: The weakref object does take some memory space. When will that reference-object be removed for garbage collection?

Comment: @claj: I'm sorry. I didn't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: You will add pointers to some object. The object gets removed, but the pointers will *not* be removed together with the object.  The references will just return a null when you look up the already removed object. The pointers takes memory. I don't really think they get GCed when what they point at is removed (but check out how Python does this, java doesn't GC them!). If they are not cleaned up by GC, you'll have to do it!